# Why i get a "Nest can't resolve dependencies"

Tags: nestjs

I'm trying to figure out why i get the following error:

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UniqueInteractionsService (?).
>   Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [0] is
>   available in the SharedModule context.

my classes:

sharedModule.ts:

```
import {Module, Global} from '@nestjs/common';
import {InteractionsService} from "./elasticsearch/interactionsService";
import {UniqueInteractionsService} from "./elasticsearch/uniqueInteractionsService";
import {EsProvider} from "./elasticsearch/esProvider";

@Global()
@Module({
    exports: [InteractionsService, UniqueInteractionsService],
    providers: [EsProvider, InteractionsService, UniqueInteractionsService]
})
export class SharedModule {
}
```

interacionsService.ts:

```
import {ESService} from "./ESService";
import {Injectable, Inject} from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class InteractionsService{

    constructor(@Inject(ESService) private readonly esService: ESService) {}

    // more stuff
}
```

uniqueInteractionsService.ts:

```
import {ESService} from "./ESService";
import {Injectable, Inject} from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class UniqueInteractionsService{
    constructor(@Inject(ESService) private readonly esService: ESService) {}

    // more stuff
}
```

esProvider.ts:

```
import {ESService} from "./esService";

export const EsProvider = {
    provide: ESService,
    useFactory: async () => {
        const esService = new ESService();
        await esService.init();
        return esService;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting UniqueInteractionsService from SharedModule. In the target module, you need to import this SharedModule and then you will be able to use UniqueInteractionsService in the targetService belonging to TargetModule through dependency injection.

Example:

```
target-module.ts:
@Module({
  imports: [SharedModule]
})
export class TargetModule {}
```